# Get data from Firestore document and append to array

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the firestore, where there is a collection of ingredients consisting of ingID, and each ingID has 4 fields

[image of my firestores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0qeg.png)

I have [String] of ingID like this : ["ing1", "ing2", ...] called byDeptIngredientID
I want to get **departmentEN** of each ingID so I have this code in viewController:

```
for id in byDeptIngredientID {
    print("start-function")
    GroceryAPI().getIngredientDept(ingID: id)
    print("finish-function")
}
```

Then I have this code in another file call GroceryAPI. This is how I get the departmentEN field:

```
func getIngredientDept(ingID: String) {
     var byDeptIngredientDept = [String]()
     let ingredientList = Firestore.firestore().collection("ingredients").document(ingID)

     ingredientList.getDocument { (document, err) in
        print("appending...")
        self.deptIngredient.append(document!.get("departmentEN") as! String)
     }
     print("deptIngredient => \(self.deptIngredient)")
}
```

As you can see that I append the **departmentEN** into **deptIngredient**, but when I print out it afterwards, the result is just empty [ ]. The result is as following:

```
start-function
deptIngredient => []
finish-function
appending...
appending...
appending...
```

So it just skip the getDocument to do other stuff then come back to do it last ? Kind of async problem maybe ? But I want deptIngredient to be like ["dept1", "dept2", ...] for further use.

Any idea how to fix this ? Thank you in advance.

**PS.** I have tried DispatchGroup with DispatchQueue, no luck on that.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code below

```
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("ingredients").document(ingID)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
       let data = document.data()
       let dataDescription = data.map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
       print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

       let ingredient = data["departmentEN"] as? String ?? ""
       self.deptIngredient.append(ingredient)

    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same result like: enter for id loop --> finish for id loop --> Document data: .....

Comment: Move the byDeptIngredientDept variable outside of the func getIngredientDept.